# WSO2 EI Custom Mediator terminates sequence execution

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

I've created custom empty mediator, which code looks like this:

```
public class ExampleMediator extends AbstractMediator { 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In next steps I've exported mediator project as deployable archive and pasted it in EI_HOME\lib directory.

I use this custom mediator in sequence in this way:

```
<inSequence>
    <log level="full"/>
    <class name="com.example.ExampleMediator"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="message" value="&quot;After custom mediator&quot;"/>
    </log>
</inSequence>
```

When i send GET request to my REST API invoking this sequence I don't see second log in console, sequence terminates and next mediators are never executed. Response from this mediation is empty message.

I expect that next mediators should be executed after returning true in mediate() method. What's wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks ok to me, except i don't see package declaration **com.example** on top of code.

It might be ESB doesn't see this mediator(exception must be in logs com.example.ExampleMediator not found) or there is another example in esb distribution (i am not sure but it is possible, name collision) same example mediator com.example.ExampleMediator. This is common name for examples. Better to provide unique package and class name.